# How to replace space with tabs

Tags: perl, escaping

I've made a function in perl script, and given three-parameter to replace words.
I want to replace space with tabs, but it failed.

The command is below.
perl ./test.pl " " "\t" "aaa"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my($from,$to,$file)=@ARGV;

while(<RH>){
    my $str = $_;
    $str =~ s/$from/$to/g;
    print WH "$str";
}
```

The result is not expected.

aaa bbb Oct-12-20:21
→　
aaa\tbbb\tOct-12-20:21

Comment: I found the way to convert \\t to tab. ```$to =~ s/\\t/\t/g;```

Comment: But then what if you want to use `\t`? Or what if you want to add a line feed? That is a bad solution.

Comment: @ikegami I found the another way, using sed.```sed -Eie 's/\s+/\t/g' files``` <- Is it better than perl script?

Comment: Could just as easily have done `perl -i -pe's/\s+/\t/g' files` with `perl`. But your code was doing more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comments, modify your command to pass a tab instead of the characters `\t`. If you are using Bash, you could for example use this command:

```
perl test.pl " " $'\t' aaa
```